# Adding New Web Front End to Farm

Tags: 2010, server-farm, farm-setup, front-end

Please Help. Is it possible to add a front end web server to a farm but not replicate the IIS sites from the first WFE? I would to have some sites on one server and some sites on the other. Can this be done?

Can you point me to any documentation?

Thanks for any help you can give. I appreciate it.

David

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no. You can only set up one SharePoint instance per box, that instance can only point to one farm, and you can't really prevent it from adding IIS sites to every server. It's just how SharePoint works.

One thing you can do if you really want to cordon off which users go to which WFE is to set that up with a non-SharePoint load balancer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is kind of what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you join the server to the farm, all IIS sites/pools will be provisioned. You'd then configure your load balancer to send traffic for x web app to VIP x and traffic for y web app to VIP y to isolate the servers being used for each web application. Once that's complete, you can stop the application pools that won't be used if you must (but do not delete them).